# Is it possible to change my IPv4 address?

Tags: windows, ipv4

At home, when I type in `ipconfig` in the command line, I would find that my IPv4 address is `192.168.8.x`. However, at office, when I type in `ipconfig` in the command line, the IPv4 address is `192.168.0.x`.

My question is, is there anyway I can configure my router, so that my IPv4 address on my machine ( and in fact all the machines in the network) is `192.168.0.x`? Or this is undoable? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) From any PC on your home network log in to your router's web interface (most likely: 192.168.**8**.1).

2) In the router's web interface, first verify that DHCP is already enabled (so you know for sure that this is the device responsible for leasing the IP addresses on your network), then change the IP address of the router itself from 192.168.**8**.1 -> 192.168.**0**.1

For example, here is what this option looks like on my Netgear WNDR3700 (under "LAN setup"):

[image]

3) After applying the change to your router and waiting a couple of minutes for it to reboot so the new IP address can be applied, you will then need to reboot all the PCs on your home network to ensure they change their IP subnets and continue to have connectivity. Don't worry about not being able to refresh the page on your web interface immediately after making the configuration change - this will be because your PC still has an IP address on the old subnet and needs a reboot.

`ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew` will technically also work but this is a pretty major networking change and I would recommend doing reboots to ensure you don't have to waste time troubleshooting anything.

After rebooting, your PCs will immediately start acquiring IP addresses on the 192.168.**0**.X range and you will have the same subnet both at work and at home.

I have actually done the same thing myself to allow our wireless users to roam between two sites, without having to worry about potential connectivity issues. In our case, we had two wireless networks with the same name and password in two different buildings. Users only log in once in one office and everything works automatically at the other one.

We use two different, non-overlapping IP ranges for the DHCP server at each site to make it impossible for IP conflicts to occur as users roam between the two offices. i.e. 192.168.1.**2-96**; and 192.168.1.**97-255**. I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary but I find it reassuring!

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.0 is a private IP range, so yes, you can change your home IP to anything between 192.168.0.0->192.168.255.255 if you like. If it were a public range (for example 8.8.0.0) then you would run the risk of making some internet sites inaccessible.

Comment: That's interesting. I never thought it would even be possible to use public IP addresses for a home network. I must try this out sometime just to see what happens!

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers: I worked for a company who was in the process of moving off a /16 block internally, and in the early days, we just changed the routers to only route those addresses internally. If you don't care about breaking external sites, you can use any address range you want on your internal network.